# Get media from specific folder

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I am creating a WhatsApp Status Saver app, but i am stuck at the point how can I access /WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses folder by use of Media Store API. I actually wanna create an app which will work on android sdk 30 or above. Kindly Ans. Thanks in Advance

Comment: for which sdk are you planning as there might be differences on the approach depending on the sdk. maybe you can further concrete where exatly you are stuck?

Comment: `/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses` Please mention full path. This path does not exist and can not exist.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014993/how-to-fetch-files-inside-hidden-folder-using-media-store-api-on-android-11

Comment: And what is exactly your problem using the media store? We have to guess if you don't tell.